How to adapt Einstein summation subscripts from 3-Index to 4-Index tensors in Numpy's einsum?
I am trying to apply frozen core approximation in order to get the effect of the forzen core orbitals on the 1-electron and 2-electron Hamiltonian. According to the notes on Page 28, the electronic  Hamiltonian is the sum of the 1-electron operator for all the electrons except the core electrons, and the 2-electron operator for all the unique pairs of electrons except for the core electrons.
$$\hat{H}_0 = E_c+ \sum_{i=1}^{N-N_c}\hat{h}_c(i)+\sum_{i>j}^{N-N_c}\frac{1}{r_{ij}}\tag{1}$$
Specifically I need to calculate:

The frozen core energy $E_c$ given with the following equation:
$$E_c=2\sum_{i}^{n_c}h_{ii}+\sum_{ij}^{n_c}{\left\{ 2(ii|jj) -(ij|ji)\right\}}\tag{2}$$
the 1-electron hamiltonian operator for an electron in the average field produced by the core electrons given in the following equation:
$$\hat{h}_c(i) = \hat{h}(i)+\sum_{j=1}^{n_c}\left\{ 2\hat{J}_j(i)-\hat{K}_j(i) \right\}\tag{3}$$
According to the notes, the frozen core operator is eventually given as
$$h_{\mu\nu}^{c}=h_{\mu\nu}+2\sum_{\rho\sigma}(\rho\sigma|\mu\nu)P_{\rho\sigma}^{c}-\sum_{\rho\sigma}(\rho\mu|\nu\sigma)P_{\rho\sigma}^{c}\tag{4}$$
where matrix$$P_{\rho\sigma}^{c}=\sum_{i}^{n_c}C_{\rho}^{i}C_{\sigma}^{i}\tag{5}$$
is supposed to be the frozen core density

I have come across a script that applies this approximation using density-fitting. I was able to adapt most of the method but I am facing some difficulties in the following part which is using Einstein summation convention. Here's the code that I believe is related to the above equations:
    constant = 2.*oneBody[core][:,core].trace()

    oneBody = oneBody[valence][:,valence]

    constant += 2*np.einsum('gii,gjj->',
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,core],
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,core].conj()
        )
    constant -= np.einsum('gij,gij->',
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,core],
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,core].conj()
        )
    oneBody += np.einsum('gkk,gji->ij',
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,core],
            twoBody[:,valence][:,:,valence].conj()
        )
    oneBody += -0.5*np.einsum('gik,gjk->ij',
            twoBody[:,valence][:,:,core],
            twoBody[:,valence][:,:,core].conj()
        )
    oneBody += np.einsum('gkk,gij->ij',
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,core].conj(),
            twoBody[:,valence][:,:,valence]
        )
    oneBody += -0.5*np.einsum('gki,gkj->ij',
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,valence].conj(),
            twoBody[:,core][:,:,valence]
        )

The first part of the equation (2) is supposed to be the trace of the 1-electron hamiltonian considering only core orbitals, using the following statement
constant = 2.*oneBody[core][:,core].trace()

The shape of oneBody is (nmo,nmo), and oneBody[core][:,core] is some sort of a mask to access only core orbitals.
The second part of the equation is taking the summation over unique pairs of core electrons. However, in my case, the shape of twoBody is (nmo,nmo,nmo,nmo), thus I think in order to apply the mask I should use
twoBody[core][:,core][:,:,core][:,:,:,core]

Specifically, my attempt for the second part of $E_c$ is coded as:
    constant += 2*np.einsum('????,????->',
            twoBody[core][:,core][:,:,core][:,:,:,core],
            twoBody[core][:,core][:,:,core][:,:,:,core].conj()
        )
    constant -= np.einsum('????,????->',
            twoBody[core][:,core][:,:,core][:,:,:,core],
            twoBody[core][:,core][:,:,core][:,:,:,core].conj()
        )

What would be the subscripts of einsum() that corresponds to the second part of the above equation in the case where twoBody has a shape of (nmo,nmo,nmo,nmo)?
Regarding equation (4), I believe that the rest of the code is supposed to be the implementation of that equation, similarly in my attempt:
oneBody += np.einsum('????,????->??',
            twoBody[core][:, core][:, :, core][:, :, :, core],
            twoBody[valence][:, valence][:, :, valence][:, :, :, valence].conj())
oneBody += -0.5 * np.einsum('????,????->??',
            twoBody[valence][:, valence][:, :, core][:, :, :, core],
            twoBody[valence][:, valence][:, :, core][:, :, :, core].conj())
oneBody += np.einsum('????,????->??',
            twoBody[core][:, core][:, :, core][:, :, :, core].conj(),
            twoBody[valence][:, valence][:, :, valence][:, :, :, valence])
oneBody += -0.5 * np.einsum('????,????->??',
            twoBody[core][:, core][:, :, valence][:, :, :, valence].conj(),
            twoBody[core][:, core][:, :, valence][:, :, :, valence])

I am modifying the mask but I am not sure what would be the subscript of einsum().

We can't really help unless you explicitly write up what you are about to do :)
The einsum documentation is pretty clear. So I think the first thing you need to do is to write up a mathematical equation, e.g. ij,jk will be matrix multiplication. So what do you want? :)

+1 I'm not sure if it would be better to start from scratch (using, for example, the notes on pg 28 of David Sherrill's notes that you provided to us) with 4-index tensors rather than trying to convert a code for 3-index tensors to a code for 4-index tensors. Once you understand einsum (which might be intimidating at first, but it is a very, very standard function) and the frozen-core approximation as explained in notes like the ones by Prof. Sherrill, it will likely not be very hard. Density-fitting is used for approximate calculations that use 3 indices and cost much less CPU time.

If page 28 is crucial for helping you, then please re-write the equations for a streamlined question ;)

I agree with @nickpapior because it took me a while to respond to this question (e.g. with the above comment) because I wanted to first look at "Page 28" and it didn't seem to be downloading on my smartphone. It turned out to be a big PDF with more than a couple equations. I think OP wants the "frozen core energy" from Eq. 4.20 and may want to implement Eq. 4.21 too. The more I think about this, the more I think the 4-index version of this problem (which is the standard version) would more easily be implemented directly, rather than basing it off the code for the 3-index approximation of it.

Thanks for adding the equations! Equations 2 and 4 involve 4 indices. Do you know the corresponding equations that involve 3 indices, which would be used when applying the density fitting approximation?

This, and the references in it, would be helpful for that: http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/df.pdf.

Do you understand how einsum works? If so, why not ask a question that is framed at asking what to calculate or how to calculate it, rather than asking how to do something with einsum that perhaps is not clear in the first place (I'm not sure if the added details have made it clear enough to @nickpapior for example).
